# Get actual row number of the record in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in which 10 records available(insert record using bulk insert) now I want select some record with row number and some specific condition. No my problem how we get actual row number of the record.

Bulk insert code

```
BULK INSERT WorkDataLoad FROM 'D:\NPfiles\xyz.txt' with ( TABLOCK )
```

Table 
    Recordline

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
Record5
Record6
Record7
Record8
Record9
Record10
```

I tried this code and result is not good

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RecordLine DESC) AS RecordLine 
from WorkDataLoad
where Recordline='Record1' or Recordline='Record3' or Recordline='Record5' 
      or Recordline='Record6' or Recordline='Record7' or Recordline='Record10'
```

Result

```
RowNumber Recordline

     1      Record1
     2      Record3
     3      Record5
     4      Record6
     5      Record7
     6      Record10
```

But I want record like this

```
RowNumber Recordline

     1      Record1
     3      Record3
     5      Record5
     6      Record6
     7      Record7
    10      Record10
```

Comment: Don't forget that there actually isn't an 'actual row number', the number will always depend on how you order your result. Maybe you could describe your actual goal a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to first assign a row number, then select only the rows you require:

```
with cteRows as
(
   Select 
      RecordLine,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordLine DESC)
   from WorkDataLoad
)
select 
    rn, RecordLine 
from cteRows
where 
    Recordline IN ('Record1', 'Record3', 'Record5', 'Record6', 'Record7', 'Record10')
```

If you run into ordering issues with '`1`' and '`10`', use something like (assuming each `RecordLine` begins with '`Record`'):

```
with cteRows as
(
   Select 
      RecordLine,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(RecordLine, 7, LEN(RecordLine) - 6) as int)  DESC)
   from WorkDataLoad
)
select 
    rn, RecordLine 
from cteRows
where 
    Recordline IN ('Record1', 'Record3', 'Record5', 'Record6', 'Record7', 'Record10')
```

Comment: Actually i want to insert these record in another table, But if there are 1 lakh record then i think it effect on execution time. what we try for this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY RecordLine DESC ) AS RowNo,
                    Recordline 
          FROM      WorkDataLoad
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.Recordline = 'Record1'
        OR t.Recordline = 'Record3'
        OR t.Recordline = 'Record5'
        OR t.Recordline = 'Record6'
        OR t.Recordline = 'Record7'
        OR t.Recordline = 'Record10'
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could EDIT YOUR ANSWER and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you need this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) RowNumer,RecordLine FROM WorkDataLoad ) qry1
WHERE RecordLine IN ('Record1', 'Record3', 'Record5', 'Record6', 'Record7', 'Record10')
```

when you have a table with 2 columns or more (`id`, `RecordLine` & ... )

Answer (score -1):

```
select recordline,rn
Select 
      RecordLine,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordLine DESC)
   from WorkDataLoad) a 
inner join WorkDataLoad b
on a.RecordLine=b.RecordLine


where 

a.Recordline in ('Record1' ,'Record3' ,'Record5' ,'Record6' ,'Record7' ,'Record10')
```